# awk function not getting called if I have a begin statement in the awk file

Tags: awk

I have an `awk` file that loads other `awk` files. Rather than calling the loading code everytime I run the main function of the file I'm trying to load everything in a `BEGIN` statement first, but if I do that the function itself never gets run. Is there anyway to have a `BEGIN` statement, and functions called from outside of the script?

My `awk` script:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

function include(includeFile) {INCLUDE_FILES[includeFile]}
function sourceIncludes()
{
    if(!l)
    {
        getline t < "/proc/self/cmdline"; split(t,T, "\0")
        scriptname=T[3]
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) 
            args=args " "ARGV[i]
        for(iFile in INCLUDE_FILES )
            inc = inc " -f "iFile
        cmd=sprintf("%s %s -v l=1 -- %s\n",scriptname,inc,args)
        system(cmd); exit
    }
}

function pkginfo(pkg)
{
    { print pkg }
}

BEGIN {
    include("wrap.awk")
    sourceIncludes()
}
```

wrap.awk contents:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

function wrap(text, q, y, z)
{
    while(text)
    {
        q = match(text, / |$/)
        y += q
        if(y >= 80)
        {
            z = z RS sprintf("%c", 0x2502) #chr(2502)#"\\u2502"
            for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                z = z FS
            y = q - 1
        }
        else if(z)
            z = z FS
        z = z substr(text, 1, q - 1)
        text = substr(text, q + 1)
    }
    return z
}
```

This is how I call everything from bash / zsh:

```
awk -f ~/.ZSH_CUSTOM/awkscripts/pkginfo.awk -e '{ pkginfo("test") }'
```

Comment: Tried your script, seems to work for me. I've GNU awk on Ubuntu 16.04. What you got there ? What's the contents of `wrap.awk` ?

Comment: wrap.awk just pushes a string onto the next line if it is over a certain length.

Comment: When I ran this on a Mac (appropriately modified), what was happening was, that the `BEGIN` commands started to run until it got to the `exit`; and then it processed `exit` before getting to the commands passed in with the `-e` switch.  Let me know if that's not what's going on for you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what's happening to me too. Without the exit it just pauses at the system call. I found that part on a post about how to include multiple awk scripts in one script. None of the solutions seem to work correctly. http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1100705

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `exit` from `BEGIN{}`, this means anything not in an earlier `BEGIN{}` or `END{}` won't be executed.

Even without the exit, your code

```
{ pkginfo("test") }
```

will not execute until a line of input (stdin) in available, this is the way awk works. You could work around that by calling a function with your code (`main()` for example) with your code, and then `exit` at the end of the last `BEGIN` block.

`awk` is quite general purpose, but it *really* wants to read lines of input, and match them to patterns. This is why your code appears to hang,.

Or, you may use

```
BEGIN { pkginfo("test") }
```

though you may need to understand the ordering of all the `BEGIN` blocks. Or, if you call `exit` at the end of the final `BEGIN` you can put your code in an `END{}` block. No input will be expected if you only have `BEGIN`/`END` blocks.

Since you are running on a Linux system you quite likely are using `gawk` rather than a plain `awk` (`nawk`, `mawk` or similar), almost certainly I think since `-e` is also a `gawk` version 4 extension ;-)
In this case you can use [`@include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Include-Files.html) which eliminates some code. Otherwise for any other awk thes wrapper script [`igawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Igawk-Program.html) seems a cleaner way to accomplish include capability.

Comment: Alright, so when people try to get you to write portable code their wanting your code to work on the more esoteric BSD or sun systems right?  I just need to worry about Linux, and maybe Mac support at the most.